# DATA Not accepted from server

Tags: php, smtp, digital-ocean, opencart2.x, zoho

I am getting the below error when trying to send a mail from my store.

```
PHP Notice:  Error: DATA not accepted from server! in /var/www/html/system/library/mail.php on line 417


Opencart version - 2.0.3.1
Email Settings:
  Protocol : SMTP
  Hostname : ssl://smtp.zoho.com
  port : 465
  Timeout : 15
```

Source code of mail.php is as below:

```
<?php
class Mail {
protected $to;
protected $from;
protected $sender;
protected $replyto;
protected $subject;
protected $text;
protected $html;
protected $attachments = array();
public $protocol = 'mail';
public $smtp_hostname;
public $smtp_username;
public $smtp_password;
public $smtp_port = 25;
public $smtp_timeout = 5;
public $newline = "\n";
public $verp = false;
public $parameter = '';

public function __construct($config = array()) {
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

public function setTo($to) {
    $this->to = html_entity_decode($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setFrom($from) {
    $this->from = html_entity_decode($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setSender($sender) {
    $this->sender = html_entity_decode($sender, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setReplyTo($reply_to) {
    $this->replyto = html_entity_decode($reply_to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setSubject($subject) {
    $this->subject = html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setText($text) {
    $this->text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setHtml($html) {
    $this->html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function addAttachment($filename) {
    $this->attachments[] = $filename;
}

public function send() {
    if (!$this->to) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail to required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->from) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail from required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->sender) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail sender required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->subject) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail subject required!');
        exit();
    }

    if ((!$this->text) && (!$this->html)) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail message required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->replyto) {
        $this->setReplyTo($this->sender);
    }

    if (is_array($this->to)) {
        $to = implode(',', $this->to);
    } else {
        $to = $this->to;
    }

    $boundary = '----=_NextPart_' . md5(time());

    $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $this->newline;

    if ($this->protocol != 'mail') {
        $header .= 'To: ' . $to . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Subject: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=' . $this->newline;
    }

    $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'From: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->replyto) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

    if (!$this->html) {
        $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
    } else {
        $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $boundary . '_alt"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

        if ($this->text) {
            $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
        } else {
            $message .= 'This is a HTML email and your email client software does not support HTML email!' . $this->newline;
        }

        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= $this->html . $this->newline;
        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt--' . $this->newline;
    }

    foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
        if (file_exists($attachment)) {
            $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');

            $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));

            fclose($handle);

            $message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . '>' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        }
    }

    $message .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . $this->newline;

    if ($this->protocol == 'mail') {
        ini_set('sendmail_from', $this->from);

        if ($this->parameter) {
            mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);
        } else {
            mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);
        }
    } elseif ($this->protocol == 'smtp') {
        $is_tls = substr($this->smtp_hostname, 0, 3) == 'tls';
        $hostname = $is_tls ? substr($this->smtp_hostname, 6) : $this->smtp_hostname;
        $handle = fsockopen($hostname, $this->smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->smtp_timeout);

        if (!$handle) {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $errstr . ' (' . $errno . ')');
            exit();
        } else {
            if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                socket_set_timeout($handle, $this->smtp_timeout, 0);
            }

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            if ($is_tls) {
                fputs($handle, 'STARTTLS' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 220) {
                    trigger_error('Error: STARTTLS not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                stream_socket_enable_crypto($handle, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
            }

            if (!empty($this->smtp_username)  && !empty($this->smtp_password)) {
                fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, 'AUTH LOGIN' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                    trigger_error('Error: AUTH LOGIN not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                    trigger_error('Error: Username not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 235) {
                    trigger_error('Error: Password not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                fputs($handle, 'HELO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: HELO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }
            }

            if ($this->verp) {
                fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>XVERP' . "\r\n");
            } else {
                fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>' . "\r\n");
            }

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                trigger_error('Error: MAIL FROM not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            if (!is_array($this->to)) {
                fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $this->to . '>' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                    trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($this->to as $recipient) {
                    fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $recipient . '>' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                        trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }

            fputs($handle, 'DATA' . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 354) {
                trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            // According to rfc 821 we should not send more than 1000 including the CRLF
            $message = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $header . $message);
            $message = str_replace("\r", "\n", $message);

            $lines = explode("\n", $message);

            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                $results = str_split($line, 998);

                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                        fputs($handle, $result . "\r\n");
                    } else {
                        fputs($handle, str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $result) . "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            fputs($handle, '.' . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            fputs($handle, 'QUIT' . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 221) {
                trigger_error('Error: QUIT not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

}

FYI: I have already tried the solution mentioned [here](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/solution-of-problem-553-relaying-disallowed-data-not-accepted-from-server-for-opencart)

Comment: Don't know if it is normal under PHP tag to post such a massice code fragments, but it is a bad tone under the most tags on SO. According to above your code accepts something else but not `250` which it expects in the stream.

Answer (score 1):

By changing SMTP Timeout to 60 seconds, I was able to resolve this issue. Obviously that's too long, but your server's negotiation with Gmail is taking longer than expected.

When you encounter that issue, it is because the server hasn't received a reply before the timeout period. Likely due to anti-spam filtering of some sort on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Because relaying is disallowed by zoho, you can't use zoho to send such emails (customized from) without changing your opencart mail code.

https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html

Leaving zoho for now...